# How to create a context sensitive help in a Java application

Tags: java

I have a Java Desktop application which requires a context sensitive help. 
For example, my Validator application gets the input as SQL statements and based on what is typed it should show possible context sensitive help.

One use case could be: when the user types "update" and then presses Ctrl+Space it should show the list of table names as context sensitive help

How do I go for this?

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete/type ahead or context sensitive help?  That latter is when you can go to a relevant part of the help file based on which dialog/part of the interface you have open.

Comment: If this is a Swing based app, look into the [GlassPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create an eclipse RCP application and extend the eclipse editor.

With eclipse is very simple create an editor and add a content assist to it.

Look at this [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_editor%3F).

Comment: The link you provide has no detail? "There is currently no text in this page, you can search for this page title in other pages or edit this page."

Comment: I think Dash1e tries us to refer this by FAQ link http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_editor%3F

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I totally understand your question. I'm guessing you're doing this in swing. Are you looking for one of those awt hover-like things (sorry, that's aweful, I just can't quite remember what it's called) like Google has when you're typing a search?

I'm not sure whether I can help you with that, but here's a method I used to match objects against a search term based on any of their attributes' values using reflection. This may be something you don't need at all, but I thought just in case I could give it to you. Hope it helps!

```
  /**
  * Returns true if any attribute in the item matches the given constraints
  *
  * @param object the object you want to match
  * @param klass the class to get the fields from (in most cases you'll just call object.getClass())
  * @param iterations how many inherited levels you want to check fields for
  * @param match the String to match fields against
  * @param ignoreField fieldNames you wish to ignore, you can give as many as you like, you can also give an
  * array of strings
  * @return whether the given object contained fields which matched the given string
  */
  public static boolean matches(Object object, Class klass, int iterations, String match, String... ignoreField) {
    if (iterations < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    boolean checkMatch = false;
    try {
      checkMatch = matchFields(klass.getDeclaredFields(), object, match, ignoreField);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(OtherHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(OtherHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if (checkMatch) {
      return true;
    } else {
      Class<? extends Object> supersSuperclass = (Class<? extends Object>) klass.getSuperclass();
      if (supersSuperclass != Object.class) {
        boolean matches = matches(object, supersSuperclass, (iterations - 1), match, ignoreField);
        if (matches) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
  * Calls matchField(field, bo, match) on each field in the given field array.
  *
  * @param fields the fields array to get the fields from
  * @param object the object to get the field values from
  * @param match the text to match fields to
  * @param ignoreField any number of fieldNames which are to be ignored.
  * @return true on first true field match
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException
  * @throws IllegalAccessException
  */
  private static boolean matchFields(Field[] fields, Object object, String match, String... ignoreField) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<String> ignoreFieldsList = Arrays.asList(ignoreField);
    for (Field field : fields) {
      if (!ignoreFieldsList.contains(field.getName())) {
        if (matchField(field, object, match)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
  * Gets the value of the field and matches the string version of it with the given match
  *
  * @param field the field to match
  * @param object the object to get the field value from
  * @param match the match to match the field value to.
  * @return
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException
  * @throws IllegalAccessException
  */
  private static boolean matchField(Field field, Object object, String match) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if (field.get(object) == null) {
      return false;
    }
    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    String value = null;
    if (type == Date.class) {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
      Date date = (Date) field.get(object);
      value = sdf.format(date);
    } else if (type == String.class || isPrimitive(type)) {
      value = field.get(object).toString();
    }
    if (value != null
            && Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(match), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(value).find()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /**
  * Checks first whether it is primitive and then whether it's wrapper is a primitive wrapper. Returns true
  * if either is true
  *
  * @param c
  * @return whether it's a primitive type itself or it's a wrapper for a primitive type
  */
  public static boolean isPrimitive(Class c) {
    if (c.isPrimitive()) {
      return true;
    } else if (c == Byte.class
            || c == Short.class
            || c == Integer.class
            || c == Long.class
            || c == Float.class
            || c == Double.class
            || c == Boolean.class
            || c == Character.class) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @alphazero No, that's not what I'm thinking of. I'm thinking of a list that pops up and filters as you type, like Google Instant.